# Perform synchronized scrolling with two scroll views

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have two scrollers in same view(like 2 vertical scrollers). I want to do something like, when i scroll one scroller the another scroll should also move by the same amount and in same direction as first one.

Is there any way i can achieve this??? Any sample will be really appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Vishal.

Answer (score 6):

I think I've done this... I did it like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  if ([scrollView isEqual: theFirstScrollView])
  {
        theSecondScrollView.contentOffset =
              CGPointMake(theFirstScrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
  }
  else
  {
        theFirstScrollView.contentOffset = 
              CGPointMake(theSecondScrollView.contentOffset.x, 0);
  }
}
```

The scrollviews must share the same delegate, and it handles the behavior in the scrollViewDidScroll method.

Comment: Hi Luvieere,  Thanks for your great herlp. It worked at my side. Yupppppy. 

Once again Thanks for your time.

Ragards,
ViShAl.

Comment: when you change the contentOffset of the other scrollview, I think that scrollViewDidScroll is triggered for it... leading to a recursive bounceback which stops slower than normally due to the deceleration factor

Answer (score 0):

You will have to intercept the touches and manually send a scrollTo: message to both scrollviews.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this as i am new to application development or do you know any sample that will help me.

Thanks,
Vishal.