# Link scrolling of two tables

Tags: macos, nstableview, appkit, nsscrollview, nsscroller

How can I link (synchronize) the scrolling of two NSTableViews (or their underlying NSScrollViews) in Cocoa AppKit?

I tried simply setting the scroller of one to the scroller of the other, but this results in the second table losing control of the scroller (i.e. it no longer appears beside the table).

An [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1438661/perform-synchronized-scrolling-with-two-scroll-views) addressed this for UIKit, but the AppKit NSScroller does not appear to provide an equivalent interface.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the ScrollView Programming Guide's section on [Synchronizing Scroll Views](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSScrollViewGuide/Articles/SynchroScroll.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003537-SW5).

Comment: Thanks!  Yet another programming guide that I had not yet stumbled on.